# notify by suitable notifications type according to the device SDK

Tags: android, notifications, version

I want to notify the user when message arrived, I used two types of notifications,(New:
 supported by >=4.1), and the other type is for older device, I write a condition to check the device SDK version and notify by the  suitable notyfication type:

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=4.1) {
 Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
         .setContentTitle("new message from" + msg.getString(ConstantsGCM.NAME_CLM))
         .setContentText(msg.getString(ConstantsGCM.BODYCLM))
         .setSmallIcon(icon)
         .setLargeIcon(bm)
         .setAutoCancel(true)
         .setWhen(when).setVibrate(viber)
         .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
         .build();

 if (EntryActivity.useSound.equals("yes"))
     if (!ring.equals(""))
         notification.sound = (Uri.parse(ring));
     else notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
 mNotificationManager.notify(110, notification);
 }else { //old type..
 NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
         new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                 .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.newlogo)
                 .setContentTitle("new message from" + msg.getString(ConstantsGCM.NAME_CLM))
                 .setContentText(msg.getString(ConstantsGCM.BODYCLM))
                 .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                 .setLargeIcon(bm)
                 .setAutoCancel(true)
                 .setWhen(when);

 if (EntryActivity.useSound.equals("yes"))
     if (!ring.equals(""))
         mBuilder.setSound(Uri.parse(ring));
     else mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);


 mNotificationManager.notify(110, mBuilder.build());
 }
```

but In older devices the notifications don't work at all! 
Any help?
point: no errors, no exceptions, just the notification doesn't apeare!

Answer (score 0):

In your else statement try this:

```
mNotificationManager.notify(110, mBuilder.getNotification());
```

Comment: How about adding a few explaining sentences? :-)

Comment: I had a similar experience and I found another question in stackoverflow. It said that in SDK <4.1 getNotification() is used, while in SDK >=4.1 build() is used. I try to find and link it.

Comment: even getNotification() Not Worked! ( getNotification() is Deprecated Use build() instead!!